# Get top three records from duplicate records having unique identity

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2. I have a table in my management studio `WORK`. I want to get the top 3 records for each employee in this table. The table has a primary key `workID` and foreign key `employeeiD`. The table is sorted descending by date. I don’t need joins to other tables. Only get the specific top 3 records for current `employeeID`. Here is my example query.

```
SELECT 
    wtop.workid, wtop.employeeid 
FROM 
    work wtop 
WHERE 
    wtop.employeeid IN (SELECT TOP 3 wsub.employeeid 
                        FROM work wsub 
                        WHERE wsub.employeeid = wtop.employeeid 
                        ORDER BY wsub.employeeid)
```

Comment: @Martin..mention the problem you are facing

Comment: The query does not return the expectedresults. I want to get top 3 records for each employeeID in the table. I`ve been trying also with count() and group by.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about using [ROW_NUMBER](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx).

Something like

```
;WITH WorkVals AS (
        SELECT  *,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY employeeID ORDER BY [Date] DESC) RowID
        FROM    Work
)
SELECT  *
FROM    WorkVals 
WHERE   RowID <= 3
```

Comment: Perfect use of ROW_NUMBER and PARTITION BY . Nice answer